# How can I detect if 2 players have the same scoreboard?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a minigame when two players are needed to start an arena !
Trying with the `c` selector for count, but it seems that doesn't work
This is the command I used:

```
/testfor @a[score_arena_min=1,score_arena=1,c=2]
```

The arena scoreboard notes the players who joined an arena, the 1 value being for arena 1.

[image: Command block image]

Can someone give me another solution than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `c` parameter is to limit the *maximum* number of targets to obtain rather than a *minimum*. For example, if there were 3 possible matches while `c` was set to 2, only the 2 closest would be selected. If there were only 1 target possible, then only that target is obtained.

Since you know the exact score and number of players you want to look for, you can check the command block's `SuccessCount` integer tag value without changing the command you're using. If it's 0, then no players were found. If it's 1, then only 1 player was found. If it's 2, then 2 (or more) players were found with that score.

[image: Repeating > Chain > Conditional Chain]

1. The command you're currently running which will set the command block's success count appropriately.

   ```
   /testfor @a[score_arena_min=1,score_arena=1,c=2]
   ```
2. Check the command block's `SuccessCount` value to ensure it is 2. Modify the XYZ coordinates to target the repeating block.

   ```
   /testforblock X Y Z minecraft:repeating_command_block -1 {SuccessCount:2}
   ```
3. **Conditional**. Action to perform as a result of there being at least 2 players that matched.

   ```
   /say Starting with players: @a[score_arena_min=1,score_arena=1,c=2]
   ```

Comment: thank you so much! I don't though the solution was that simple.